Want to follow a polymer paper but can't understand their units
I read a paper that was formulating different polymer mixes where their recipe units were g-1 (see attached image on their recipes). I am assuming that its g%g (grams per 100 grams of material), but I wanted to make sure and its not just material/g (would change the recipe greatly if I wanted to repeat).
Thank you. :)
EDIT:
https://doi.org/10.1002/app.38638

To emphasize, I know g-1 means per gram, what I need help with is why it is used in the context of recipe measurements to formulate the polymer as there is no mention of per gram of what, so I wanted to ask if this is common. Taken from Maurice: I need help understanding "What is the thing expressed per gram ?"

So, I added the paper in question and their listed table. The unit is stated to be per gram.
I understand its per gram as I mentioned in my post, but I am unsure about if they measured it directly (then it should be just (g) right)? Or is it the total percent of gram of the entire recipe?

I am sorry, but the numbers contained in the given table have no meaning. The amount of $\ce{H2O}$ cannot be expressed in $\pu{g^{-1}}$, which means "per gram". It can be expressed in grams, not in $\pu{g^{-1}}$. What is the thing expressed per gram ? Other question : what is the meaning of MQ ?

MQ is the type of polymer silicone resins that forms a 3D spherical chain. The M is the end-capping type (eg hexamethyldisilazane), in which the naming convention comes from the 3x of methyl groups, and the Q represents silanol. I took the table directly from the article. I also do not understand why they put g-1 that's why I wanted to ask if it is commonly seen in chemistry as my background is more mechanical. I just want to emphasize that I also do not understand why the authors put g-1 and asked this question to help clarify.

I think it's terrible style and they try to convey that it is gram. I'm not sure as I have not read the paper. Usually in table headings you put the quantity divided by the unit, so that in the cell there is only a number. Something like "m(stuff) / g". But I'm just guessing here.

Thank you Marti!  I had a thought that was the case as well.
